# Is there a buildin(or 3rd party) function in Python to get the exception caught in context?

Tags: python

Is there a function in Python, e.g. get_exception, so I can do this:

```
try:
    can_raise_anything()
except:
    ex = *get_exception()*
    print('caught something: ' + str(ex))
```

I know in Python 3, I should use `except BaseException as ex:` to do the task. I'm just curious to see if there is a function can do that.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to catch absolutely everything? Even `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`? Most of the time, even `except Exception` is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`except BaseException as e` also works in Python 2.

If you really want to use a function for some reason, `sys.exc_info()` will return a tuple whose second element is the exception object. (The first element is the exception type, and the third element is the traceback.)

Answer (score 1):

The `except` block can receive an additional part which looks like this:

```
try:
    stuff()
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Some libraries (including builtin ones) provide specific `Exception` types, which can be used for reacting better depending to the type of error found. Combining this with the fact you can have as many `except` blocks for one `try` block, you can make a very fail-safe app. Example of a complex `try-except` block:

```
try:
    result = a / b
except TypeError as e:
    print "Woops! a and b must be numbers!"
    result = int(a) / int(b)
    print e
except NameError as e:
    print "A variable used doesn't exist!"
    print e
except ArithmeticError as e:
    print "It seems you've gone past infinity, under atomicity or divided by zero!"
    print e
except Exception as e:
    print "Something REALLY unexpected happened!"
    print e
```

Built-in exceptions used in the example:

- TypeError: When the type of a variable is unexpected (e.g adding strings and numbers)
- NameError: A variable used is not existant
- ArithmeticError: General math error
- Exception: Any kind of error, can be used for simple `except`s or just for "everything else"

A list of built-in exceptions and their descriptions for Python 2.x can be found at http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html.
Note: Usually custom libraries have comments describing the custom exceptions they raise.